# wstringstreams treating -ve values strangely

Tags: c++, stringstream, wchar-t

I am trying to use wstringstreams as a buffer to serialize some data.

The problem I am having is the data gets somehow corrupted. To elaborate the problem, have a look at the following code snippet:

```
std::vector<long> items;
for (long i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
{
    items.push_back(-1);
}

std::wstringstream ws;
for (auto & val : items)
{
    ws.write((wchar_t *)&val, sizeof(long));
}
auto resultStr = ws.str();
```

I am expecting at the end the resultStr will have length `100 * sizeof(long)`. But the size I am getting is `2`. What is interesting is that instead of inserting `-1` to the items container, if I insert 1 instead, the resultStr is as expected `100 * sizeof(long)` big and has the right contents.

With normal stringstreams also I am getting the correct results.

Why is wchar_t based streams messing up the treatment of -ve values?

**P.S.** I am on Windows 7, vs2015 upadate3 and code compiled and run on x86 debug

Comment: You're trying to write binary data into a wstringstream, why? I wouldn't expect any random data to survive that necessarily since it's supposed to be characters.

Comment: Also giving `write` a length of `sizeof(long)` should typically tell it to write 4 or 8 *characters*, not *bytes* to the output, which shouldn't be right.

Comment: ok, what would be a better way to do this then? use stringstreams?

Comment: I feel there's an XY problem here. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to convert the container contents into a byte buffer

Comment: If you want a byte buffer, why then are you trying to use `std::wstringstream`. which writes to a buffer of `wchar_t`s, not bytes?

Comment: It is common for the `WEOF` macro to have the value `-1`. Might affect the operations of the stream.